# socketCAN vs OEM drivers

Tags: embedded, can, linux

I have a Kvaser mPCIE card on my embedded Linux machine. Most standard Unix distributions come with a socketCAN driver module which takes care of any CAN devices present in the system, hence I can easily communicate with the CAN bus using socketCAN only.

On Kvaser's website they have their own drivers available which are based on socketCAN, but are distinctively different. Once I install them, I am unable to use socketCAN any more as it gets blacklisted from auto-loading.

What are the advantages of using Kvaser's own drivers (if any) and should I be using them?

Answer (score 2):

I emailed Kvaser about this and their answer was this:

"The Kvaser Drivers for Linux are not based on socketcan.  The Kvaser Linux driver is designed to match the CANlib SDK API we provide for the Windows platform.  This makes porting applications that use Kvaser hardware between Windows and Linux easier.

The socketcan support is a completely different driver that conforms to socketcan requirements and API.

Installing the Kvaser Linux driver will cause the Kvaser socketcan driver to be blacklisted.  We do not want both drivers trying to grab the same resource."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the advantages of using Kvaser's own drivers (if any) and should I be using them?

The main advantage is that you can use any interface from Kvaser, either by PCI, USB or networked in your application without knowing how the interface connects.
And you could deploy the same source code on Windows, since the API is identical.

However, manufacturers supporting their proprietary drivers is still frowned upon in the Linux world.